# searching through UISearchBar,with sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uisearchbar

Search through uisearchbar ,with sqlite.
For example the word "home" written in uisearchbar, be sent to query:

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE content MATCH '…..' // here '….'  to be sent "home"

```
-(NSArray *)titles{

NSMutableArray * retval = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

NSString * query = @"SELECT * FROM table 1 WHERE content MATCH '…..' ";

sqlite3_stmt * statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query.UTF8String, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {………..}}};
```

I want to know if this is possible ,and a link with an example.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure your view controller implements the UISearchBarDelegate protocol then add the following method

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self titles:searchText];
}
```

Modify your ***titles*** method to accept a string as parameter:

```
-(NSArray *)titles:(NSString *)toMatch
{
NSMutableArray * retval = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM table 1 WHERE content MATCH '%@'", toMatch];

sqlite3_stmt * statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query.UTF8String, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {………..}}};
```

Make sure your viewcontroller is the delegate for the UISearchBar.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this post:
[text search too slow on sqlite db on tableview on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418127/text-search-too-slow-on-sqlite-db-on-tableview-on-iphone)