# Pandas + SQLite "cannot use index" error

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am using pandas, sqlite, and sqlalchemy to search a bunch of strings for substrings. This project is inspired by [this tutorial.](https://plot.ly/python/big-data-analytics-with-pandas-and-sqlite/)

First, I create a sqlite database with one column of strings. Then I iterate through a separate file of strings and search for those strings in the database.

I have found the process to be slow, so I did some research and found that I needed to build an index on my column. When I followed the instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418127/text-search-too-slow-on-sqlite-db-on-tableview-on-iphone) in the sqlite shell, everything seemed to work just fine.

However, when I try to make an index in my python script, I get the "cannot use index" error.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection
import datetime as dt



def load_kmer_db(disk_engine, chunk_size, encoding='utf-8'):
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    j = 0
    index_start = 1
    for df in pd.read_csv('fake.kmers.csv', chunksize=chunk_size, iterator=True, encoding=encoding):
        df.index += index_start
        j += 1
        df.to_sql('data', disk_engine.raw_connection(), if_exists='append', index=True, index_label='kmer_index')
        index_start = df.index[-1] + 1


def search_db_for_subsequence(disk_engine, sequence):
    """

    :param disk_engine: Disk engine for database containing query sequences
    :param sequence: Sequence for finding subsequences in the database
    :return: A data frame with the subsequences of sequence
    """
return pd.read_sql_query("SELECT kmer FROM data INDEXED BY kmer_index WHERE '" + sequence + "' LIKE '%' || kmer || '%'", disk_engine)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('kmers', type=str, metavar='<kmer_file.txt>', help='text file with kmers')
    parser.add_argument('reads', type=str, metavar='<reads.fastq>', help='Reads to filter by input kmers')

    # Get the command line arguments.
    args = parser.parse_args()
    kmer_file = args.kmers
    reads_file = args.reads

    # Initialize database with filename 311_8M.db
    disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///311_8M.db') # This requires ipython to be installed

    load_kmer_db(disk_engine, 200)

    #****** Try explicitly calling the create index command
    #****** using the sqlite module.
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect('311_8M.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE INDEX kmer_index ON data(kmer);")

    reads = SeqReader(reads_file)
    for read in reads.parse_fastq():
        count += 1
        sequence = read[1]
        df = search_db_for_subsequence(
            disk_engine,
            sequence
        )
```

One can see that I first tried to create an index by passing the proper keyword arguments to the to_sql method. When I did that alone, I got an error stating that the index could not be found. Then I explicitly made the index through the sqlite3 module, which yielded the "cannot use index" error.

So now it appears that I have made my index, but for some reason, I am not able to use it. Why would that be? And how does one create an index using the pandas api instead of having to use the sqlite3 module?

Comment: That error message "cannot use index" seems to relate to the `pd.read_sql_query()` call and not the part where you create the index directly using the sqlite3 module.

Comment: Yes it appears that I am successfully creating the index, so why is it that I am unable to use it?

Comment: I think it has to do with your use of LIKE '%[some term]%'

Comment: E.g. queries like this LIKE '[some term]%' can use an index but LIKE '%[some term]%' cannot.

Comment: Interesting, after testing int he sqlite shell it appears that you are correct. So I will just have to look into when one can use an index when using the LIKE syntax. Thank you

Comment: You're very welcome. I will post my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message "cannot use index" seems to relate to the `pd.read_sql_query()` call and not the part where you create the index directly using the sqlite3 module.

A query with `some_col LIKE '%[some term]%'` cannot use an index on `some_col`. Queries with `some_col LIKE '[some_term]%'` on the other hand can make use of an index on `some_col`.